# How can I add a value for mysql: Empty value for port

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have forgotten the phpMyAdmin root login password. I have tried a couple of options but nothing is working due the error shown here https://snag.gy/n07uIf.jpg. I have tried to reinstall phpMyAdmin after purging. I could not complete the complete removal of phpMyadmin and its configuration due to the above error.

I tried to reinstall phpMyAdmin, again I am getting the error message.

What is the best option for me now? What I can do to fix the error and complete the phpMyAdmin installation.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit `/etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf` and set the following value:

```
dbc_dbport='0'
```

Then reconfigure `phpmyadmin`:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

You could also restart the mysql service with `--skip-grant-tables` in order to login without a password:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -uroot mysql
```

Then update your password for the root user:

```
UPDATE user SET password = PASSWORD('YOURPASSWORD')
  WHERE user = 'root'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now you will need to restart mysql and you should be able to connect using your new password:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try and back to you with the result.